# Configuring turtlebot3_slam_gmapping

Tags: ros, laser, ros-kinetic, 3dslam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to unsubscribing the **turtlebot3_slam_gmapping** node from the topic **/scan** and in place of that, subscribing **turtlebot3_slamp_gmapping**  to a topic published by **/scan_to_scan_filter_chain** ? To elaborate, I want SLAM node to get filtered information from the node **scan_to_scan_filter_chain** rather than the original information from the **/turtlebot_lds**.

rqt_graph:

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299210/configuring-turtlebot3_slam_gmapping/) by [sujeet](https://answers.ros.org/users/36611/sujeet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-07-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-07-31**:
Are you asking about changing the topic that `gmapping` publishes to?

**Comment by [sujeet](https://answers.ros.org/users/36611/sujeet/) on 2018-07-31**:
@jayess nope, I'm just asking about changing the topic of subscription for turtlebot3_slam_gmapping from turtlebot3_lds to scan_to_scan_filter_chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're looking for the `<remap>` tag then. `roslaunch` allows you to change a node's topics during launch time with it. so, you'd have something like

```
<remap from="scan" to="new_scan_topic"/>
```

According to the [documentation on the wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/remap)

> The `<remap>` tag applies to all subsequent declarations in its scope (`<launch>`, `<node>` or `<group>`).

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2